# Can't Convert to JSONArray for showing in ListView

Tags: java, php, json

i'm try to convert json array from internet to listview. the php code in server work correctly and return the json string below.
the result json in logcat is :

```
11-09 20:47:04.170: I/AllNotes >> jSon >>(429): {"notes":{"3":{"note_subject":"dshjdsfjsdfsdhf","note_id":"4","note_date":"0000-00-00"},"2":{"note_subject":"dshjdsfjsdfsdhf","note_id":"3","note_date":"0000-00-00"},"1":{"note_subject":"dshjdsfjsdfsdhf","note_id":"2","note_date":"0000-00-00"},"0":{"note_subject":"dshjdsfjsdfsdhf","note_id":"1","note_date":"0000-00-00"},"7":{"note_subject":"dshjdsfjsdfsdhf","note_id":"8","note_date":"1391\/8\/19"},"6":{"note_subject":"dshjdsfjsdfsdhf","note_id":"7","note_date":""},"5":{"note_subject":"dshjdsfjsdfsdhf","note_id":"6","note_date":""},"4":{"note_subject":"dshjdsfjsdfsdhf","note_id":"5","note_date":""}},
"success":"1"}
```

my JSONParser class is :

```
package ir.mohammadi.android.nightly;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = null;

    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Make HTTP connection
        try {

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

            Log.i("Input stream >> ", is.toString());

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();

            Log.i("JSON string builder >> ", json.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json.substring(1, json.length()));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

error is : `at notes of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray`

the code that show json in list view is :

```
package ir.mohammadi.android.nightly;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AllNotes extends ListActivity {

    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> noteList;

    JSONArray notes = null;

    JSONObject jSon = null;

    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_message";
    private static String KEY_NOTE_ID = "note_id";
    private static String KEY_NOTE_SUBJECT = "note_subject";
    private static String KEY_NOTE_DATE = "note_date";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.note_list);

        noteList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        new LoadAllNotes().execute();
        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                String note_id = ((TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.list_lbl_id)).getText().toString();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NoteDetail.class);
                i.putExtra("note_id", note_id);
                startActivityForResult(i, 100);
            }
        });
    }

    public class LoadAllNotes extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllNotes.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("لطفا صبر کنید...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            UserFunctions userFunctions = new UserFunctions();

            jSon = userFunctions.getAllNotes("12");

            Log.i("AllNotes >> jSon >>", jSon.toString());

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                if (jSon.has(KEY_SUCCESS)) {
                    String success = jSon.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                    if (success.equals("1")) {
                        notes = jSon.getJSONArray("notes");
                        for (int i = 0; i < notes.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = notes.getJSONObject(i);

                            String id = c.getString(KEY_NOTE_ID);
                            String subject = c.getString(KEY_NOTE_SUBJECT);
                            String date = c.getString(KEY_NOTE_DATE);

                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            map.put(KEY_NOTE_ID, id);
                            map.put(KEY_NOTE_SUBJECT, subject);
                            map.put(KEY_NOTE_DATE, date);

                            noteList.add(map);
                        }

                    }
                } else {

                    finish();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            jSon.getString(KEY_ERROR_MSG), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                    Log.i("AllNotes >> No nightly >>", "...");

                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), login.class);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(AllNotes.this,
                            noteList, R.layout.list_item, new String[] {
                                    KEY_NOTE_ID, KEY_NOTE_SUBJECT,
                                    KEY_NOTE_DATE }, new int[] {
                                    R.id.list_lbl_id, R.id.list_lbl_subject,
                                    R.id.list_lbl_date });
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and the php code is :

```
public function getNotesList($user_id)
    {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `note_subject`, `note_date` FROM `tbl_notes` WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id'");

        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            $response = array();
            $response["success"] = "1";

            $response["notes"] = array();

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $note = array();
                $note["note_id"] = $row["id"];
                $note["note_subject"] = $row["note_subject"];
                $note["note_date"] = $row["note_date"];

                array_push($response["notes"], $note);
            }
            return $response;
        }
    }
```

and

```
if ($tag == 'getNotesList') {

                            $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
                            $result = $db->getNotesList($user_id);

                            if ($result) {
                                error_log("Index getNotesList Json >>" . json_encode($result) . "\r\n", 3,
                                    "Log.log");
                                echo json_encode($result, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
                            } else {
                                $response["error"] = "1";
                                $response["error_message"] = "no row";
                                echo json_encode($response, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
                            }
                        }
```

how can i fix this? thanks.

Comment: post full code because your json string only contain Json object's not any jsonArray.

Comment: edit the question to full code

Comment: The issue is that the JSON coming from the server is not a JSON array, it is a collection of objects, each keyed by an index.  The Android parser cannot create a JSON array if one does not exist in the source data (i.e. the list of objects is placed between `[]` with no keys).  I'm removing the Android tag as this is an issue directly related to how the PHP server generates the JSON data.

Comment: Why do you cut 1 character?

jObj = new JSONObject(json.substring(1, json.length()));

Comment: because "a" in showing before json. i search for it and found that is for utf-8 encode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
  JSONObject notes = jSon.getJSONObject("notes");
```

instead of

```
JSONArray notes = jSon.getJSONArray("notes");`
```

Because your json String is collection of JsonOject's it's not contains any JsonArray.

you can use following json checker site before parsing it to known the structure of Json String

http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: I changed to JSONArray but not fixed. copy JSON in the lisnk and show correctly the result

Comment: i use this link to create the code : [^] (http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

Comment: not to JSONArray change it to JSONObject and see your json string it only contain "{" means it contain only json object's not any jsonarray

Comment: Thanks. fix it. after this i changed to `JSONObject c = notes.getJSONObject(Integer.toString(i));`